# Spring Rest Repositories Reference JPA Entity in Mongo Document

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to use a `JPA Entity` into `Mongo Document` as a document reference. I've one JPA Entity `User` and Mongo Document `Product`. `Product` has a relation `testedBy` which references `User` entity.

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

}

public class Product {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    @DocumentReference
    private User testedBy;

}
```

The application runs and I can see the rest repositories response. However, the [testedBy](http://localhost:8080/products/p1/testedBy) relation url does not work giving 404 error on browser and `2023-05-24 14:48:13.852  WARN 69291 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException: EntityRepresentationModel not found!]` on the logging console.

Is it possible to make this work? Here is the [github repo url](https://github.com/roykyle8/spring-data-jpa-and-mongo).

[image: User Rest API][image: Product Rest API][image]